# stored procedure with parameters in MYSQL

Tags: mysql

I have a question about the stored procedure:

Create a stored procedure named `format_currency` that accepts a character and a double number. It will return a `VARCHAR(32)` with the symbol in the front, followed by the number to 2 decimal places.
For example, `format_currency('$', 123.4)` should return $123.40

Here is my code:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE format_currency(IN c VARCHAR2, IN n DOUBLE(9,2))
AS
BEGIN
  SELECT   CONCAT(c,',' n);
END;
```

It's not working, I have no idea how to write codes inside BEGIN and END.

Many Thanks for your help.

Henry

Comment: Is there any error?

Comment: what have you researched or tried so far? This is not a free write-my-code, do-my-thinking or even do-my-googling service. We'll help you with your attempt to solve your problem, but, unless it's something fairly trivial, most people here will not just hand it to you on a plate. This site is manned by volunteers giving their free time to assist you. In return they generally ask that you respect that fact by showing you spent some time of your own to try and solve your issue before asking others to spend theirs. Your time is not more valuable than ours. Thanks.

Comment: `VARCHAR2` is an Oracle-specific data type. MySQL uses `VARCHAR`.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of procedure I suggest to use function:
Code:

```
DELIMITER $$
DROP FUNCTION IF EXISTS test_f$$
CREATE FUNCTION test_f(a varchar(22),b double(9,2)) returns varchar(64)
BEGIN
SET @RET = (select concat(a,b));
return @RET;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

## Test Run:

```
mysql> select test_f('$',123);
+-----------------+
| test_f('$',123) |
+-----------------+
| $123.00         |
+-----------------+
1 row in set (0.10 sec)

mysql>
```

Comment: Good answer, but I will point out that the question looks a bit like homework and may need to use a stored procedure for whatever it is they're trying to accomplish.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but  It's homework requirement , I have to use stored procedure which can not return value(s).

Answer (score 0):

```
DELIMITER\\
CREATE PROCEDURE format_currency (a CHAR, b DOUBLE(9,2))
BEGIN
  declare ret VARCHAR(32);
  set @ret = (SELECT CONCAT(a,b));
  select @ret;
END
DELIMITER\\
call format_currency('$',123);
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar question and nothing the other people answered worked for me in MySQL. Here is a working solution with 2 parameters as "SIGN" and "MONEY" and creating a variable called "NEWRESULT" that you delcare, set as 0, and then set as the concat of "SIGN" and "MONEY".

```
    DELIMITER //
    CREATE PROCEDURE format_currency`enter code here`
    (IN SIGN char(1),IN MONEY double(9,2))
    BEGIN
        declare NEWRESULT char(8);
        set NEWRESULT=0;
        SET NEWRESULT=(SELECT CONCAT(SIGN,MONEY));
        SELECT NEWRESULT;
    END//
    DELIMITER ;
```